# Extract element from one list with elements from another list, recursively

Tags: list, haskell, recursion

I want to use one list e.g. `[1, 2, 4]` to get elements from another list e.g. `[1, 0, 2, 5, 1, 0]` using recursion so that the results are stored in a third list, as if the first list denotes the position of each element wanted from the second list, like this:

```
[1, 0, 2, 5, 1, 0]!!1 = 1
[1, 0, 2, 5, 1, 0]!!2 = 0
[1, 0, 2, 5, 1, 0]!!4 = 5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do here is apply the same function for every element in a list, which is what `map` is for.

Assuming you have:

```
indexes = [1, 2, 4] 
values = [1, 0, 2, 5, 1, 0]
```

What you need to do is

```
map (values!!) indexes
```

This will return the desired `[0,2,1]`. You're using partial application to do `values!!index` for each of the values in the list of `indexes`, and then you save it to a list that will have the same length as `indexes`.

If you wanted to do this recursively in a way that is actually visible from the code, you could do this:

```
obtainValues [] values = []
obtainValues (x:xs) values = [values !! x] ++ (obtainValues xs values)
```

Notice the pattern matching in `(x:xs)`, where x is the first element of the list (let's say an Int, in this case), and xs represents the rest of the list ([Int]).

Comment: You do not need the second line `obtainValues [x]...`. When you pattern match `[]` and `(x:xs)`, you already match all contructors of lists.

Comment: How about integrating this obtainValues with results from other functions, though? I have a function that takes a triple and outputs a list. Like this: `portInfoX (3, 1, 20) = [0, 2, 5, 4, 6]`. But when I put it in I'm getting type errors everywhere.

Comment: I'm not sure where you're using obtainValues there. The result of that function, that is a list, can be used as a parameter in obtainValues, but you would not be able to use the tuple. You should probably open a new question for this tho.